# Am I missing an equilibrium point?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I am trying to identify all the equilibrium points of this system, and am only concerned with the first quadrant:

$$x'=x(a-x-ay),
 \\ y'=y(b-bx-y)$$

Where a and b are parameters greater than 0. When I calculate the equilibrium points by setting x'=y'=0, I get (0,0), (a,0), (0,b). The problem is, when I plot the nullclines with varying values of a and b, I can get a fourth equilibrium point, as an x-nullcline and y-nullcline intersect. Why is this equilibrium point not showing up when I initially calculate them in terms of my parameters? Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$x'=0 \implies x=0 \quad \text{or} \quad \frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{1}=1$$

$$y'=0 \implies y=0 \quad \text{or} \quad \frac{x}{1}+\frac{y}{b}=1$$

There're $4$ combinations for choosing the conditions such that $x'=y'=0$.

The fourth equilibrium point is given by

$$
\left \{
  \begin{align}
    \frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{1} &=1 \\
    \frac{x}{1}+\frac{y}{b} &=1
  \end{align}
\right.$$

which gives the solution $(x,y)=\left( \dfrac{ab-a}{ab-1},\dfrac{ab-b}{ab-1} \right)$

Comment: Thank you! I knew I was missing something. I upvoted your answer, but I only have 13 reputation points, so it does not display.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin {cases}
x'=x(a-x-ay)
 \\ y'=y (b-bx-y)
\end{cases}
$$
You didn't solve this system:

$$
\begin {cases}
(a-x-ay)=0
 \\ (b-bx-y)=0
\end{cases}
$$
Where $x \ne 0,$ and $y \ne 0$